# why we can't find function satisfying this conditions?

Tags: complex-analysis

why we can't find function satisfying this conditions?

In fact >>I don't know how to start solving
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have likely just learned the [maximum modulus principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle). This is a question whose purpose is to gauge whether or not you understand the statement of this principle.